# simulating linux's "cd" command in python , and persist the directory change after the program exits

Tags: shell, python-3.x, freebsd

i used the following code so to persist the directory change after the program exits but the drawback is that it opens a new sub shell , so each tim a run it a new subshell is opened

```
import os, subprocess
newpath="/usr/local/www/nginx"
oschdir(newpath)
subprocess.call(['bash'])
```

is there a wayout , i want to do this in FreeBSD 10.1,python3 , irrespective of the shell . 
Is there a way out.

Comment: The subshell here is opened for `bash` not for the directory changing. I'm confused. Do you need to run `bash` or not? Running `bash` here isn't part of changing the working directory of the python script.

Comment: Running `bash` like this also does absolutely nothing as it has no input and no script to run so it should just immediately exit.

Comment: ...and if you passed `bash` a `cd` command, it would change its own directory, and then exit -- *not* changing the parent (Python) process's directory.

Comment: I wanted to persist the directory change after the program exits so i opened bash ,, if i dont do this  ,the directory change doesn't persist , thats why .

Comment: Why do you think that's true? (`os.chdir()` has effect on the immediate process whether or not a subprocess is invoked afterwards; try printing `os.getcwd()` with and without the bash call, and you'll see that it's the same either way).

Comment: but i reach to a changed directory after program exits